# Java Preferences API Classloading Challenges

Tags: spring-boot, classloader

**Problem:**

*I have a custom implementation of java.util.prefs in a maven jar module.*
I am providing the system property to *-djava.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=com.blah.CustomePrefsFactory*
to my Spring boot app that is using the custom preferences.

When the Spring boot app uses the Preferences for the first time, the Java.util.Preferences.java tries to load the CustomePrefsFactory using the
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().

This results in errors as nested jar classes are not available to a system class loader of the spring boot app.

Is there a way to make nested jar classes available to the system class loader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The short answer is no.**

System `ClassLoader` delegates to the Bootstrap `ClassLoader` and Extension `ClassLoader` and then tries to load classes from classpath, but not from nested JARs.

**You have to implement or use an existing `ClassLoader` that supports that functionality.**

Comment: Since the Preferences implementation was eventually exposed as a REST service, the need to implement or use a custom classloader was removed.